# WPF Bind TextBox to List<string> using variable for index

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have a Window that displays a variable number of identical UserControls which contain (among other things) a TextBox. A single ViewModel serves both the window and the UserControls. How do I bind the UserControl's TextBox's Text property to an element of a List-of-strings in my view model when the required index is passed to the constructor of the UserControl?

I also need Mode="TwoWay" and UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged".

Using VS2013, .NET 4.5.2, and MVVM-Light framework.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use an extra property for the instead of hacking around trying to bind a List<string> to a string property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to create a new ViewModel class to serve just the UserControls, one per object. Same class that creates the UserControls now creates the ViewModels and passes one in the UserControls ctor.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a new property in your ViewModel that would act as a "wrapper" for that call.

```
public string MyElementItem {
   get { return myStringList[myAwesomeIndexFromConstructor]; }
   set { 
      myStringList[myAwesomeIndexFromConstructor] = value; 
      RaisePropertyChanged(...);
}
```

And then bind to this new property and it should do the magic for you!

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyElementItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: It's the UserControl's constructor that knows the index; the ViewModel contains the List that feeds all of the UserControls. I've updated my post to clarify the bigger picture.

Comment: Are you able to "feed" the ViewModel with the Index Value somehow?
Either by passing the value to its constructor (depending on how its set) or by sending a command that would contain the index value to be used.

Comment: But how would the view model keep track of which index corresponds to which UserControl? Are you saying the UserControl should somehow set a property in the ViewModel right before it asks the ViewModel for the string?

Comment: Are you using a Shared ViewModel for each seperated UserControl?

Comment: Yes, that's why the ViewModel's property is a List. The ViewModel serves the Window that contains the UserControls as well as the UserControls.

Comment: Hmm. I have a feeling that you may not be able to solve this issue with xaml alone. Worst case scenario, you will have to add some "glue" code to the xaml.cs.

However, it could be possible if you create a new class to act as a collection. Derived from the INotifyPropertyChanged, make sure to raise the PropertyChanged everytime one of the items are updated and use this new CollectionClass and pass it along with the UserControls in their constructor. This will make sure that each instance of the UserControl is using the shared Collection.

Comment: Added "shared viewmodel" info to my post.